# Insert C++ vector by "replacing" the iterator at the insertion point (with a complication)

Tags: c++, vector, insert, iterator, erase

Is there a simple way to add a vector into another vector, and to delete 
the iterator at the insertion position afterwards (practically "replacing the iterator" with a new vector)?
What i wish to do is (read comment in Code):

```
struct Data
{
    Data(int i) :d(i) {}
    vector<Data> vec;
    int d;
};
vector<Data> dataVector = { Data(1), Data(2), Data(3) };
dataVector[1].vec = { Data(41), Data(42) };

// Task: replace Data(2) in dataVector with dataVector[1].vec to get {Data(1),Data(41),Data(42),Data(3)};

for (auto it = dataVector.begin(); it != dataVector.end();) {
    if ((*it).d == 2) {
        it = dataVector.insert(it,(*it).vec.begin(),(*it).vec.end());
        // Now delete Data(2) somehow
        // it = dataVector.erase(...
    }
    else it++;
}
```

is there an elegant way to achieve this without incrementing "it" n times or using additional variables? 
In general I would have vectors of arbitrary length, and I would prefer to add append the new vector at the end, but that is not crucial.

Comment: Have you tried `dataVector.insert(it, it->vec.begin(), it->vec.end()); it = dataVector.erase(it);`?

Comment: Yes, but the iterator is invalid after `dataVector.insert(it,it->vec.begin(),it->vec.end())`, so you have to get the new one by getting the return value of insert. The problem is, that the return value is always an iterator to the Beginning of the inserted data

Comment: I just found a solution: `it = dataVector.insert(it+1,it->vec.begin(),it->vec.end());
   it = dataVector.erase(it-1);` maybe it is not the best one, but it seems to work

Comment: Yup, that is an answer :) I realized I put the wrong thing in the comment after re-reading (missed an `-` and `+`), but glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution: 
    `it = dataVector.insert(it+1,it->vec.begin(),it->vec.end());`
    `it = dataVector.erase(it-1);`
Maybe it is not the best one, but it seems to work even for insertinf at the beginning/end of the vector. Thanks for your help!